# The list of instances is empty on the GCP console's VM instances page

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I don't know which forum I should select for this question. Because of that I'm writing this question here.

One of our GCP console users started having issues while listing the instances on the VM instances page of the GCP console. This happened on October 4, 2022.

The user doesn't have access to other pages on GCP console. We were not able to test this with other pages, unfortunately.

The Google Cloud SDK (gcloud) commands are working as expected. There is another user account with the exact permissions and the other user doesn't have this issue.

The user is a Windows user and tried different browsers (Chrome, Edge and Firefox) with no luck. We also tried to clean up the cache of the browsers, deleting the cookies and deleting everything all together. These were not helpful as well.

Do you have any idea what would be the issue and possibly a solution/workaround to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anything interesting in the Cloud Logging??

Comment: Use the browser debugger Console and Network tabs to figure this out. Most likely you have an add blocker or anti-virus blocking page loads.

Comment: @jabbson, nothing interesting there. The logs show that the user was able to retrieve the list of instances with the message "user@example.com retrieved a list of instances." There were also no warnings or errors.

Comment: @john-hanley, I will check this with the user. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thank you for your suggestion. The issue is really related to the antivirus software installed. When the antivirus is not running, the user was able to access the VM instances page.